# Split names separated with commas when surnames are also separated with commas

Tags: python, list, split

I have a following database field:
AUX: Smith, J., Jones, M. & Ford, S.
There can names from one up to 15 and others are separated by comma and last one separated by &

How can I split this into list, where list[1]=Smith, J, list[2]=Jones, M. and so forth?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe the data even more.  Does every name have only one initial, or could "Tolkien, J. R. R." be in this list?  Are the initials always single letters, or could a rouge have entered a name like "Astaire, Fred."?  Are the initials always followed by a period?

Comment: Tolkien, J.R.R. could be on the list. As far as I know there are no whole first names, only one initial per name but there can be several first names. But what makes it too difficult for my skills is that I have to separate it every second comma (that is between names, not on surname, first name) and also on &-character .

Answer (score 3):

```
def parseNames(namestr):
    namestr   = namestr.replace('&', ',')
    nameparts = [namepart.strip() for namepart in namestr.split(',')]
    it = iter(nameparts)
    return zip(it,it)    # return list of part-pairs

def nameStr(name, fmt="{lastname}, {firstname}"):
    return fmt.format(lastname=name[0], firstname=name[1])

names = [nameStr(name) for name in parseNames("Smith, J., Jones, M. & Ford, S")]
```

gives you

```
['Smith, J.', 'Jones, M.', 'Ford, S']
```

Comment: I'll try this one tomorrow at work. Thank you for your answer. Yours, Tapani

Comment: That solution work just fine after I figured I had too old version of Python in our server and got a new version installed. Thank you again.